# Using Angular Waypoints in the Controller

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, jquery-waypoints

I am trying to use 
https://github.com/zumba/angular-waypoints in one of my ionic projects.

I have the code setup as mentioned in the readme.

Here is the template snippet

```
<div zum-waypoint="waypoints"
 down="flags.on"
 up="flags.off"
    ng-show="shown()" style="opacity:{{opacity}}; ... </div>
```

The documentation does not say anything about how to use the waypoints.flag.on value in the controller.

The template above is part of a custom directive - and in my directive's controller, I have tried doing:

```
    $scope.waypoints = {}
    $scope.waypoints.flags = {}

    $scope.$watch('waypoints.flags', function() {
        console.log("Flag on changed to "+JSON.stringify($scope.waypoints) + " for card = "+$scope.id)
        if ($scope.waypoints.flags.on){
            alert("Mark notification as Read for "+$scope.id)
            console.log("up changed" + $scope.waypoints.flags.on + " for id = "+$scope.id)
        }

        if ($scope.waypoints.flags.off){
            alert("2 Mark notification as Read for "+$scope.id)
            console.log("down changed " + $scope.waypoints.flags.off + " for id = "+$scope.id)
        }
    })
```

But this is never called back.

However, in my template if I use:

```
{{waypoints.flags.on}} // {{waypoints.flags.off}}
```

They show up as true // false , though after a digest cycle.

Please let me know what is the correct way of using the waypoint flags in the controller.

Thank you.

Comment: What's it like for you now ? I have the same issue and I was wondering if you managed to solve it.

Comment: Could not get it going then - dropped it - will take another attempt soon

Comment: Very encouraging, leave a note if it works ;)

Comment: Did you anyone pick this back up and get it going?

Answer (score 0):

That's what I did: a custom directive. It doesn't require zumba's angular-waypoints, only jQuery waypoints.

```
app.directive('waypoint',function(){
  return {
    link: function(scope, $this, attrs) {
      $this.waypoint({
        handler: function() {
          scope.$parent.last = scope.post.id;
          scope.$parent.$apply();
        }
      })
    }
  }
});
```